# How to access the variable in other test RESt Assured

Tags: junit, rest-assured

I am new to REST Assured framework. I have written the below code. It's working fine.

```
private static String result;

@Test
    public void getStudentById() {  

    Response response = 
        given().
            header("authToken",userToken).
            pathParam("SNum", "A123").
        when().
            get("/students/{SNum}").
        then().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            body("firstName",equalTo("JOHN")).
        extract().
            response(); 

      result = response.print();      
      System.out.println("Response************************" + result);
    }
@Test
    public void StTest() {
System.out.println("Response************************" + result);    
}
```

In the response I am getting JSON data

```
{"list":
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "SNum": "A123",
            "title": "Mr",
            "firstName": "JOHN",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "id":1 ,
            "SNum": "A12",
            "title": "Mr",
            "firstName": "James",
            "lastName": "Pesr"
        }
   ]
}
```

Here, I need `id` in second test. So I am printing result variable in second test but it is getting `null`. How to get the result variable in second test.

Comment: What you want to do with id? Get first id and assert that it equal to some value or you want assert that your list contain some id or contain a few ids?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jsonPath to get id in the second test:

list[1].id

So you should be able to do:

int id = RestAssured.with(response.asString()).getInt("list[1].id");